# Optimization for specific argument without template

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I ran into some optimized code that is fast, but it makes my code ugly.

A minimal example is as follows:

```cpp
enum class Foo : char {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B'
};

struct A_t {
    constexpr operator Foo() const { return Foo::A; }
};

void function_v1(Foo s){
   if(s == Foo::A){
      //Run special version of the code
   } else {
      //Run other version of the code
   }
}

template<class foo_t>
void function_v2(foo_t s){
   if(s == Foo::A){
      //Run special version of the code
   } else {
      //Run other version of the code
   }
}

int main(){

   // Version 1 of the function, simple call, no template
   function_v1(Foo::A);

   // Version 2 of the function, templated, but call is still simple
   function_v2(Foo::A);

   // Version 2 of the function, the argument is now not of type Foo, but of type A_t
   const A_t a; 
   function_v2(a);

}
```

For that last function call `function_v2` will be instantiated with a specific version for `A_t`. This may be bad for the size of the executable, but in experiments, I notice that the compiler is able to recognize that `switch == Foo::A` will always evaluate to `true` and the check is optimized away. Using gcc, This check is not optimized away in the other versions, even with `-O3`.

I'm working on an extremely performance intensive application, so such optimizations matter. However, I don't like the style of `function_v2`. To protect against calling the function with the wrong type, I would have to do something like enable_if to make sure the function isn't called with the wrong type. It complicates autocompletion because the type is now templated. And now the user needs to keep in mind to call the function using that specifically typed variable instead of the enum value.

Is there a way to write a function in the style of `function_v1`, but still have the compiler make different instantiations? Maybe a slightly different coding style? Or a compiler hint in the code? Or some compiler flag that will make the compiler more likely to make multiple instantiations?

Comment: Your example does not compile for a number of small mistakes. You will get better engagement with your question if we can just copy-paste the code and use it as-is.

Comment: While it sometimes doesn't make much difference, any unrelated problem or error in your [mre] can distract from the real issue you're asking about. So please make sure that your [mre] only describes or replicates the problem you ask about, and don't have other unrelated issues (which unfortunately your code do have, is that enumeration really correct?).

Comment: Check your example on https://gcc.godbolt.org/ to make sure it actually compiles, and the assembly is what you say it is.

Comment: my bad, will fix

Comment: do not use template, overload the function with specific parameter type...

Comment: Given this code, how did you determine if the condition is optimized away or not?

Comment: @Sedenion I thought of that, but my code often has multiple of these variables in a single function. That would quickly lead to an explosion of the amount of function definitions. I don't mind these being in my compiled code, but it seems ugly to have them in my source.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I took a slightly more complicated version of this example that actually calls something and timed it. v2 called with the specific type was faster.

Comment: @ThijsSteel if you want optimized code without branch (and you are right), function overloading is the common way to do...

Comment: `That would quickly lead to an explosion of the amount of function definitions` and all you do is to hide that amount with `if()`s inside functions....

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter now, but generally it's good to have code in your question that actually reproduces the issue you're talking about (a [mcve] mentioned in the second comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to write a function in the style of function_v1, but still have the compiler make different instantiations?

If we expand your example a bit to better reveal the compiler's behavior:

```
enum class Foo : char {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B'
};

struct A_t {
    constexpr operator Foo() const { return Foo::A; }
};

void foo();
void bar();

void function_v1(Foo s){
   if(s == Foo::A){
      foo();
   } else {
      bar();
   }
}

template<class foo_t>
void function_v2(foo_t s){
   if(s == Foo::A){
      foo();
   } else {
      bar();
   }
}

void test1(){
   function_v1(Foo::A);
}

void test2(){
   function_v2(Foo::A);
}

void test3(){
   const A_t a; 
   function_v2(a);
}
```

And compile with `-O3`, we get:

```
test1(): # @test1()
  jmp foo() # TAILCALL
test2(): # @test2()
  jmp foo() # TAILCALL
test3(): # @test3()
  jmp foo() # TAILCALL
```

See on godbolt.org: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/443TqcczW

The resulting assembly for `test1()`, `test2()` and `test3()` are the exact same! What's going on here?

The `if` being optimized out in `function_v2()` has nothing to do with it being a template, but rather the fact that it is defined in a header (which is a necessity for templates), and the full implementation is visible at call sites.

All you have to do to get the same benefits for `function_v1()` is to define the function in a header and mark it as `inline` to avoid ODR violations. You will effectively get the exact same optimizations as are happening in `function_v2()`.

All this gives you is equivalence though. If you want **guarantees**, you should forcefully provide the value at compile time, as a template parameter:

```
template<Foo s>
void function_v3() {
    if constexpr (s == Foo::A) {
        foo();
    }
    else {
        bar();
    }
}

// usage:

function_v3<Foo::A>();
```

If you still need a runtime-evaluated version of the function, you could do something along these lines:

```
decltype(auto) function_v3(Foo s) {
    switch(s) {
        case Foo::A: 
            return function_v3<Foo::A>();
        case Foo::B: 
            return function_v3<Foo::B>();
    }
}

// Forced compile-time switch
function_v3<Foo::A>();

// At the mercy of the optimizer.
function_v3(some_val);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would this also work if my function is far too large to be inlined?

Comment: @ThijsSteel It will work exactly as well as the template version, whatever that means. The inlining logic of compilers is essentially the same in both scenarios as far as I know.

Comment: @ThijsSteel The compiler may freely choose to not inline the function as it may freely choose to inline, if `inline` was not specified.

Comment: @Sebastian `inline` has basically no influence on optimization anymore. All it does is exclude the function from ODR checks. It was always a hint in the first place anyways.

Comment: `switch` / `case` is what glibc uses for a couple special constants to make GCC compile special versions of the int->string loop with compile-time-constant divisors of 10, 8, and 16, vs. the same loop with a runtime variable divisor that will compile with an actual `div` instruction (much slower) in `_itoa` for numbers that fit in a single integer type:   https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdio-common/_itoa.c#L170-L187 (@ThijsSteel).

Comment: I think the optimization has to do with the inlining, not just the availability of the function in a .h. If i force the compiler to not inline the functions, i do get different results: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MKvG4jj3f

Comment: @ThijsSteel That's what inlining is. Unintuitively, the `inline` keyword doesn't come into play, only the availability of the potentially inlinable code. The only thing `inline` does is relax ODR.

Comment: Yes, but then "All you have to do to get the same benefits for function_v1() is to define the function in a header and mark it as inline to avoid ODR violations. You will effectively get the exact same optimizations as are happening in function_v2()." is a bit confusing, because the code i actually want to use this in is far too large to be inlined. So yes, the inline keyword doesn't come into play, but it is still the inlining that makes the optimization possible.

Comment: @ThijsSteel If `function_v1()` is too big to be inlined, then so is `function_v2()`. If `function_v2()` gets inlined, then `function_v1()` would as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about using template specialization:

```
template<class T>
void function_v2_other(T s){
    //Run other version of the code
}

template<class T>
void function_v2(T s){
   function_v2_other(s);
}

template<>
void function_v2(Foo s){
   if(s == Foo::A){
      //Run special version of the code
   } else {
      function_v2_other(s);
   }
}
```